# Access protected base class type for other base class template initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, typedef, protected

I have a piece of code where I make use of the [BaseFromMember](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) idiom to be able to create a proper inheritance relationship for the class I am actually interested in (called `Derived`). I stumpled upon the fact that it is not possible to access protected (or private) base class types before the body of the derived class. See my code below:

```
struct BaseFromMember
{
    //protected: // comment/uncomment this line
    using T = int; // using declaration/typedef

  protected:
    BaseFromMember()
      : t_(1)
    {}

    const T& t() const { return t_; }

  private:
    const T t_;
};

template<class T>
class Base
{
  public:
    Base(const T& t)
    {}
};

class Derived
    : private BaseFromMember // private, protected, public doesn't matter here
    , public Base<typename BaseFromMember::T> // this does not work for protected type T
{
    using T = typename BaseFromMember::T; // works

  public:
    Derived()
      : BaseFromMember()
      , Base(BaseFromMember::t())
    {}
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
}
```

As expected, the problem does not depend on the fact which modifier is used to derive `Derived` from `BaseFromMember`.

However, `Base` can only be initialized if the using declaration in `BaseFromMember` is public, otherwise I get an error with both, gcc (4.8.2) and clang (3.4-1). I consider this behaviour unexpected, especially because `typename BaseFromMember::T` is accessible in `Derived`'s body.

I was not able to find any related topic on stackoverflow. I found [this thread](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2014-March/033213.html) though, although I am not certain if it addresses the same issue.

Question: Did I do something wrong or do I assume something that should not be assumed? Or this is maybe just a compiler bug?

Note: Even more disturbing to me is the fact that the keyword `typename` does not seem to have any effect when establishing the inheritance of `Derived`. Maybe I just did something very silly?

Note: I am not sure if the term *initalization* is correct in this context as used in the title of this thread. Please let me know if another term would be more appropriate. Of course, I would also like to know if any other terms that I use are inappropriate :).

Comment: `BaseFromMember` is not a dependent name. Seems like you don't need `typename`. Also, this compiles both ways with `g++ 4.7.3` in C++11 mode

Comment: How curious: `4.7.3` works with `typename` and fails without. `4.8.1` fails either way.

Comment: It seems like it should work. There's an example in **11/6** that boils down to `class A { protected: struct B {}; }; struct D : A::B, A {};`, with the comment of `the use of A::B as a base-specifier is well-formed because D is derived from A, so checking of base-specifiers must be deferred until the entire base-specifier-list has been seen.`

Comment: Added compiler versions after @Dark Falcon's second comment.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik mentions the exact same thing as is stated in my original link. I believe the order of base classes in its role as an example to be important as well, though - which is not the case for my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.

A first step might be the reduction of your code to something shorter. I believe this code still exhibits the behaviour you describe:

```
class A {
protected:
  typedef int T;
};

template <typename T> class B {};

class C : public A, B<typename A::T> {};
```

Indeed, this fails to compile with clang 3.4.1 and gcc 4.8.2, whereas earlier version (4.5,4.6,4.7) happily accept it (I ran each compiler in C++0x mode).

Comment: Even though this is not an answer, it helps to narrow down/clarify the problem, by providing a minimal working example (which OP's code is not). Furthermore, I cannot post this code snippet as a comment. I considered editing his question and deemed it too invasive. I don't see any harm in leaving this visible here.